# Is cron job server intensive If scraping millions of URL and updating data to mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, web-scraping, cron, instagram-api

I'm trying to build a small react native app project using instagram as a test subject. I want to be able to display instagram videos from their URL, and was wondering what is the best approach to do so?

The ideas is to use puppeteer (or similar library) and cherrio to scrape the url of hundreds of instagram urls, and then grab the video source url, and store it into mongodb. Since Instagram's CDN video url changes every couple of days, I would have to somehow scrape the url every so often so it doesn't return bad timestamp error. Is using cron jobs to automate and constantly get new video url every so often and store it in mongodb a good approach?

How fast will it grab new urls, if the list continues to grow to like hundreds of thousands, maybe more? Will it be too intensive on the server?

Is there a better way?

Comment: @Brad please explain more?

Answer (score 1):

the biggest challenge you'll be facing would be not getting rate limited by instagram. i.e. any large website would only allow a certain number of requests per time slot (could be per minute/second/etc.) from the same ip/browser combo. in worse case scenarios your ip would be totally blacklisted by them. or even the whole subnet your server belongs to would get blocked.

another hurdle would be the resource hungryness of puppeteer/chromium. it would use up all of your cpu and memory if processing pages in parrallel. then everything else running on that server will slow down or not respond at all sometimes.

some sites such as amazonon, google, etc. employ anti-bot stratergies like re-captchas to prevent scraping.

i'm not saying it's not possible. it takes a lot of resources, knowledge and effort to get through all the blockages but it can be done. i'm running my own `change detection & notification` service (link in my profile) and it's a fulltime job most of the time. i'm managing 1 front-end server + 13 scraper servers (each server runs 20 puppeteer browsers in parallel each with their own ip address pretending to be a unique user/browser/ip/session combo).

also, you should look to something other than cron for scheduling. just write your own service does things in parallel and recovers automatically/gracefully in case of server restarts or process terminations.

what i'm saying is you need to invest heavily in developing a whole infrastructure and manage things continually for scraping millions of pages. specially if it's from the same website.